# How to save array (integer) to text file in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have array of this integer type:

```
object = [[6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2], [6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1], [6, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2], [6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]]
```

How can I save this to an xyz.txt file in this format with 5 lines:

```
6 0 2 3 5 0 
0 2 1 0 3 2
6 0 1 0 4 1 
6 1 1 0 3 2 
6 2 1 2 1 2
```

The following code returns the error

```
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    for line in object:
        txt_file.write(" ".join(line) + "\n")
```

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: Replace `join(line)` with `join(str(item) for item in line)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a string list from your integer list.

```py
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    for line in object:
        line_str = [str(n) for n in line] # create string list from integer list
        txt_file.write(" ".join(line_str) + "\n")
```

or you can do it by this way,

```py
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    for line in object:
        txt_file.write(" ".join([str(n) for n in line]) + "\n")
```

Another way is create a string from your integer list and write that string into your file

```py
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    for line in object:
        string_line = ''
        for n in line:
            string_line += f"{n} "
        txt_file.write(string_line.strip() + "\n")
```

Comment: You don't need a `list`, `.join` works with generator expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to convert the nested lists to lists of strings:

```
with open('xyz.txt', 'w') as txt_file:
    for line in object:
        txt_file.write(" ".join(map(str, line)) + "\n")
```

*As a side note, naming your variable `object` (or any other keyword of the language) is a bad habit.*

Comment: more pythonic would be to use a list comprehensio tho

Comment: @Matiiss _ I wouldn't necessarily say so. Why replace this code with more text?..

Comment: I'm a pragmatist regarding the question, but as far as I know Guido van Rossum was inclined to move `map` into the standard lib (see [here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)). So I'm inclined to agree with @Matiiss :)

Answer (score 0):

use the np.save() function

```
np.savetxt('array.txt',array,fmt='%d')
```

**fmt='%d'** will produce the integer output